# Freeform - required fields blank after errors

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform 4.2.0 and EE 2.8.1 .  I've got the form below, with required fields. Freeform does recognise that the fields are required and returns the error messages, but any correctly filled out fields are blank.  Is there a way to make freeform remember the correctly filled out fields when returning errors?

```
  {exp:freeform:form
    form_id="3" 
    form_name="student_bookings"
    return="/student-accommodation/thank-you"
    notify_admin="yes"
    admin_notify="email@email.com"
    notify_user="yes" 
    user_email_field="student_email"
    user_notification_template="student_user"
    inline_errors="yes" required="property_details|rent_agreed|deposit_agreed|room_type|student_name|student_address|student_tel_number|student_email
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using input fields like this:

```
<input type="text" class="your-class" name="FIELD_NAME" value="" placeholder="Enter FIELD_NAME" />
```

Use this:

```
{freeform:field:FIELD_NAME
    attr:class="your-class"
    attr:placeholder="Enter FIELD_NAME"
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, that looks like it will work.